# Hide non-comments in github issues

Tags: github, github-issues

Github issues shows a lot of "status" changes that I would like to be able to hide, sometimes I really only want to see comments, and these status updates can become quite numerous in some issues requiring a lot of scrolling, is there a way to hide these or only show comments made by users when looking at an issue?

[image]

---

going on @kaffarell answer, added an item to github discussions if anyone else is interested to vote/comment on it: https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/4579

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, this is not possible right now. If you want, you can submit a feature request to Github on their community site.